# Wordpress Sub-Domain URL

Tags: wordpress, url, subdomain, cpanel, alias

I'm new to WordPress and I've run into a problem that I can't figure out. I was hoping you could help me.

So, I have a domain, let's call it: www.abcd.com

A few days ago I came up with an idea and wanted to create a website for it. "abcd.com" doesn't really relate to my idea at all, so I figured I could create a subdomain. I created it with the following address: www.newidea.abcd.com

Is there any way I can hide the "abcd" from the URL? I tried creating an Alias but to no result.

I'm using cPanel and WordPress if that's worth mentioning!

Thank you.

Comment: You can't "hide" the domain so your only choice is to buy a new one instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Wordpress configuration questions should be asked on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and this is not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: If this was possible, nobody would be safe on the web anymore. Think about www.yourbank.myserver.com and I would be able to hide the "myserver.com" part. I could phish your banking details from you and you couldn't tell the difference between the real www.yourbank.com and my phishing site from the URL.

So it's not possible, that's exactly how the domain system was designed to work and enabling such a feature would open huge security holes.

But hey, domains are cheap. You can buy www.newidea.sometld if it's free. Maybe try some of the newer gTLDs if your desired .com is already taken.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks!